# jQuery initialize on click?

Tags: jquery

I am using [jScrollpane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) for a [clients'](http://www.koodoocreative.co.uk/~stagesca) website. The problem I have, Is the scrollbars initialise fine on the "Welcome" tab. The "Products" tab I would also like that tab to have the same scrollbar as the "Welcome" tab.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for the tabs and am not loading any jQuery associated with them, It is purely default.

My **HTML** code is as follows :

```
<div class="tab-content">
          <div id="home" class="tab-pane active scroll_tab">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2>
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </div>
          <div id="about" class="tab-pane">
            ABOUT CONTENT
          </div>
          <div id="services" class="tab-pane">
            <?php 
                $page_id = 11; 
                $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); 
                echo '<h2>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h2>';// echo the title
                echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // echo the content and retain Wordpress filters such as paragraph tags. 
            ?>
          </div>
          <div id="case_studies" class="tab-pane">
            CASE STUDIES CONTENT
          </div>
          <div id="contact_us" class="tab-pane">
            CONTACT US CONTENT
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am then initialising the jScrollpane plugin on document.ready() within a function.

The jQuery Code is as follows :

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {    

/* Scrollbars */
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll_tab').jScrollPane();
    $('.tab-content > .tab-pane, .pill-content > .pill-pane').jScrollPane();
});
});
```

How do I force the jScrollPane(); to initialise on each tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put up an example on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: What sort of example @Gavriel ?

Comment: your html, css, js so we can see it in action

Comment: BTW I thing you don't need to call $('.scroll_tab').jScrollPane(); because it also is included in  $('.tab-content > .tab-pane')

Comment: You can see it here : http://www.koodoocreative.co.uk/~stagesca

Thanks

Comment: what's the problem I see the scroll on 2 long "tabs", the rest doesn't have enough text in it to need the scroll. If you put more text in them the'll have the scroll I guess

Comment: So you can see in the "Welcome" tab the scroll and in the "Products" tab it also has a tab? I think you'll need to firebug on the "Products" tab as their is a lot more content and no scrollbar

Comment: no I can't. Sorry. But see my answer below, I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea: try calling  $('.tab-content > .tab-pane.active').jScrollPane() AFTER the click that changes to another tab. I think the problem is that while the other (not 1st) tabs are hidden the jScrollPane doesn't calculate their height correctly.

Comment: Nice answer. Giving me a rough idea of what to do, I've made the following jQuery $('.services_tab a').click(function() {
  $('#services').jScrollPane();
 }); which does work, But when you doubleclick the products tab :S?

Comment: you need to do it not as an onclick, but within the onclick callback that's already there (when I click on Products it calls a callback that changes the tab.) There, inside that fuction, but AFTER it displayed the new tab you should do it, because only then the tab has it's real height. Your onclick function runs before the tab is displayed, so it's still height=0, as it was before your "fix"

Comment: Not quite with you on that @Gavriel the tabs are using Twitter Bootstraps' tabs.

Comment: I don't know bootstrap, but you have <a data-toggle="tab" href="#services">, I guess the data-toggle causes bootstrap to add an onclick function on the link. I'm pretty sure that you can do something like: don't add data-toggle, instead have onclick="yourFunc(this)", and in yourFunc you can call a bootstrap function to change the tab, and after that call finishes you can call the jScrollPane

Comment: Thanks for that @Gavriel also thanks for your time. It's now jumping to the href="#" any ideas how I prevent?

Comment: you are a star. I've got there eventually. Many thanks for your help